# Call JavaScript Function from PHP output

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function from my PHP output.

The problem is that the function does not fire.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="build_workout_functions.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </head>
<?php

  if ( isset( $_GET[id] ) ) {

  echo '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="build_workout_functions.js" charset="UTF-8">
        getUserProgram('.$_GET[id].');
    </script>';
  }

?>
    <body id="login-bg"> 

        <div class="workout_table">

            <select name="days">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
                <option value="E">E</option>
                <option value="F">F</option>
            </select>

            <select name="muscles" onchange="getExercies()">
                <option value="legs">legs</option>
                <option value="back">back</option>
            </select>

            <select name="exericse"><select>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript code:

```js
function getUserProgram ( userId ) {

    alert(userId);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_user_program.php",
        data: {id: userId}
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });

}
```

Comment: You should not mix "src" attribute AND code inside of a `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- Script tags should be either in the `<head>` or the `<body>` (yours is not)
- You're already loading jQuery and `build_workout_functions.js` in your head. Your PHP output doesn't need to reload them.
- You should not put content in a `<script>` tag that has a `src` attribute.

Consider [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) here:

> If there *is* a [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) attribute, the element must be either empty or contain only [script documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts) that also matches [script content restrictions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements).

What this means is that you should only provided JavaScript commented content when using the `src` attribute. An example of this is provided for us on the w3c website:

```js
<script src="cool-effects.js">
 // create new instances using:
 //    var e = new Effect();
 // start the effect using .play, stop using .stop:
 //    e.play();
 //    e.stop();
</script>
```

Comment: These are the "must be learnt" things before considering other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just write as html format, if `if` condition is met, then your script will be written and so executed, otherwise not.

Note: I assumed that you wrote first two lines of `<script>` as trials and you call `getUserProgram()` as trial, too.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET[id]))
{
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="build_workout_functions.js" charset="UTF-8">
    getUserProgram('<?php echo $_GET[id]; ?>');
</script>

<?php
}

?>
```

I also echo `$_GET[id]` in the function call and I left `$_GET[id]` as it is, it can be wrong by the way.